# Multi level dropdown menu (Tree dropdown) with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hi I was developing a multilevel tree dropdown component. But am kind of confused on how to develop the component, since the data might have so many levels and sub levels. Currently am stuck with a better approach or idea

I know how to hardcode the data and create the menu like below with pure HTML and css. How can I do with Angular with backend dynamic data? Thanks in advance.
HTML:

```
<ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Offices</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">New York</a>
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Sample data:

```
data =  [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'root1',
          children: [
            { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
            { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'root2',
          children: [
            { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
            {
              id: 6,
              name: 'child2.2',
              children: [
                { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

Comment: Is that Menu list is static or dynamic?

Comment: Its like a dropdown menu. Data should be dynamic

Comment: Can you share the Sample data??

Comment: `[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];`

Comment: Check this:https://stackblitz.com/angular/egbkpeqdryb?file=app%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts

Comment: Hi I cannot use material in my project. ANy suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: Try for Jquery third party library

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make your component completely dynamic in this case but you can have a array of objects in typescript which has all your options in the menu and use `*ngFor` to iterate.

**In .ts**

```
let menu = [{
        'About': '#link'
    },
    {
        'Services': '#link'
    }, {
        'offices': [{
            'Chicago': '#link'
        }, {
            'Los Angeles': '#link'
        }, {
            'New York': [{
                'Information': '#link'
            }, {
                'Book a Meeting': "#link"
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

and iterate through these nested objects in your html. If you do not have too much things to add remove frequently from your menu it's better to go with hard coding.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for the answer. If yes and for new viewer, then I have created a plugin for Angular which creates a Multilevel menu.

Here is a [NPM Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-material-multilevel-menu) and [Github Link](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu), the documentation is very sweet and simple.

Just in case, if you wanna see more examples, I have a  [demo](https://multilevel-menu-demo.web.app/) for you and this is the [Github Repo](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu-demo) of the demo.

If something doesn't work for you, and you still wanna use this plugin, then [create an issue here](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-material-multilevel-menu/issues) I'll help you out.

P.S. it works in IE11 as well.

Thanks